# Trying to read in chars to save to current string but its being appended to previous string too

Tags: c, string

I am trying to add a certain number of characters to each character string inside a struct, however some strings that are being saved into a string also append to the previous string.  How do i make it so that it doesn't append to the previous string.

```
typedef struct {
char first[7],initial[1],last[9], street[16], city[11], state[2], zip[5], sex[1];       
int age, tenure;
float salary;
} payroll;

payroll details[15]
void readFile(payroll *details) {
int i=0;

FILE *fIn;


if (fopen_s(&fIn,"payfile.txt","r") != 0) {
    printf("Failed to open payroll.txt for reading.\n");
    return;
}

while (!feof(fIn) && i<1) {
    char buf[MAX] , age[3], tenure[2], salary[10];      

    fgets(buf,MAX,fIn);
    strsub(buf, details[i].first, 0, 6);
    printf("%s\n",details[0].first);    //gets string chars 0-6
    strsub(buf, details[i].initial, 8, 8);
    printf("%s\n",details[0].first);    //somehow initial adds to first
    strsub(buf, details[i].last, 10, 18);   //initial still gets what it was
    strsub(buf, details[i].street, 20, 21); //supposed to get until the next
    strsub(buf, details[i].city, 23, 38);   //string and read
    strsub(buf, details[i].state, 40, 41);
    strsub(buf, details[i].zip, 43, 47);
    strsub(buf, age, 49, 50);
    strsub(buf, details[i].sex, 52, 52);
    strsub(buf, tenure, 54, 54);
    strsub(buf, salary, 56, 61);

    details[i].age = atoi(age);
    details[i].tenure = atoi(tenure);
    details[i].salary = atof(salary);

    i++;
}
}

void strsub(char buf[], char sub[], int start, int end) {
int i,j;

for (j=0,i=start;i<=end;i++,j++) {
    sub[j] = buf[i];
}
sub[j] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: Cool story. What's your question?

Comment: Can you show us how your `details` defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem is that the fields `char first[7],initial[1],last[9],...` are all 1 char too small.  `strsub(buf, details[i].first, 0, 6);` extracts 7 chars from buf to put into `first`.  So far so good.  But then strsub() appends the NUL byte into first's 8th char, which is undefined behavior as first is 7 chars long.  The UB you see is the apparent concatenation of `last` onto `first`.

Increase the length of each field by 1.

Comment: BTW:  It took me 4 times in re-reading your post to see that it had a question "How do i make ...previous string."  Folks tend to skim the posts.  I did not see the question and looked at the code as a whole.  You will likely get speedier responses by using that pesky '?'  "How do i make ...previous string?"

Comment: Ok I will make sure I put that '?'.  Thanks :)